# link_to disable_with not disabling button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

Currently have the following button to an external link:

```
  <%= link_to('Connect Dwolla',
        @dwolla_link,
        class: 'btn btn-lg btn-warning',
        data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Redirecting to Dwolla.com..."}) %>
```

Upon clicking the button, the spinner and text appear but the button is not disabled.

Comment: which browser are you trying it?

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam Chrome

Comment: Look at my answer and the discussion in the issue link that I posted.
Also, try using `button_to` instead of `link_to` in this case. See if that works.

Answer (score 6):

There is a known [issue](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/306) that `disable_with` does not work `link_to` for some browsers. Make sure you test it on a browser where it works.

Also, try using `button_to` instead of `link_to` in this case. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

An update, the following allows to keep all the css with disabled button

```
<%= link_to 'Connect Dwolla', {}, :disabled => true, class: 'custom-css' %>
```